# How can get the data from dynamic columns by LINQ To Entities in ASP. Net core C#?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

I want to build a dynamic report by Asp.net core -EF-, that is received columns names from user, and then create SQL query depended on these inputs, I wrote this code. But it is return list of columns names, not return the list of data inside these columns.

```cs
public async Task<Collection_Response<string>> GetReportDataAsync(int Report_Type, List<string> columns, DateTime Start_Date, DateTime End_Date, string Lang)
{
    Collection_Response<string> result = new Collection_Response<string>()
    {
        Is_Success = false,
        Messages = new List<Message_Item>()
    };

    try
    {
        var report_Query = (from p in db.Children
                            join e in db.Centers
                            on p.Center_ID equals e.Center_ID
                            where p.Joining_Date >= Start_Date && p.Joining_Date <= End_Date
                            select ($"new  {string.Join(", ", columns)} ")).ToList();

        result.Data = report_Query;
        result.Is_Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Messages.Add(new Message_Item() { Message = err.Handle_Exception(ex) });
    }
    return result;
}
```

What I should write to return the data of selected columns by user and display as report?

Comment: I need to confirm do you want to create new object in select() method which  the count of properties are based on the `List<string> columns` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the data of these selected columns by user, each time these columns are changed based on user selection

Comment: Because `columns` contain the properties from two models, So i think you may need to match it in select method manually. just like `select new {Column1 = columns.Contains("Column1") ? p.Column1 : null,....}`

Comment: Can you please give me an example or any tutorial to can help me more , thank you